# How to save custom datetime in cakephp 3 for created & modified field?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to save the following data. But it's not saving the datetime fields.
Created is saving current datetime in cakephp way & the others are null.

How can I save custom datetime?

Thanks in advance

```
foreach ($passwords as $key => $value ) {
    $data['id']             = $collection_id;
    $data['name']           = $value['password'];
    $data['collection_id']  = $collection_id;
    $data['photo_count']    = $value['photos_count'];
    $data['download_count'] = $value['downloaded_users_count'];
    $data['created']        = $value['created'];
    $data['modified']       = $value['modified'];
    $data['expires_at'] = $value['expires_at'];
    $saveData[] = $data;
}

$passwords = $this->Passwords->find('all')->toArray();
$patched = $this->Passwords->patchEntities($passwords, $saveData);
foreach ($patched as $entity) {
    $this->Passwords->save($entity);
}
```

Comment: Is this copy paste directly from your project? Because in this code you are using wrong quotes.

Comment: Sorry, it may be changed during the question. In project it's okay. Anyway, I'm fixing it on the question.

Comment: What is the content of `$value['created']` and `$value['modified']`? You need to convert the date in a correct format (such as `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM`).

Answer (score 2):

I've fixed the Issue. Just have to use as follows-

```
        $data['created']        = new Time($value['created']);
        $data['expires_at']     = new Time($value['expires_at']);
```

And to do so, have to use this.

```
use Cake\I18n\Time;
```